# How to loop until *ipconn.Read() has read all data sent to it in go

Tags: go

I was sending some data using *ipconn.Write method in go , but it seems *ipconn.Read() can only read 20 bytes at a time

here is server sending data

```golang
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8888")
conn, err := ln.Accept()
tmp := make([]byte,10000)
tmp = []byte("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
conn.Write(tmp)
```

here is the client receiving data

```golang
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8888")
data := make([]byte, 100000)
conn.Read(data)
fmt.Println(string(data)) // prints only first 20 chars
```

If i again call conn.Read(data) I get another 20 characters

Is there any way to read all the data or loop until the connection is closed ?

Comment: `ioutil.ReadAll` will do what you request, but that precludes any possibility of interactivity on the TCP connection.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks , it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ioutil.ReadAll will read all the data from the tcp stream. Be careful as it doesnt return until the connection has been closed.